# How to determine error when Python print(os.system("command")) in Windows

Tags: python, os.system

I followed the directions in the Byte of Python book, regarding creating a program for backups.
At the end of it, my python code keeps returning Backup FAILED. I had it print the error, which it gave: -1073741515
I've searched and searched and can't seem to find an answer to the meaning of the error code. See the python code below:

```
import os
import time

# 1. The files and directories to be backed up are
# specified in a list.
# Example on Windows:
source = [r'C:\Users\ftbbo\PycharmProjects\helloworld']
# Example on Mac OS X and linux:
# source = ['/Users/swa/notes']
# Notice we have to use double quotes inside a string
# for names with spaces in it. We could have also used
# a raw string by writing [r'C:\My Documents'].

# 2. The backup must be stored in a
# main backup directory
# Example on Windows:
target_dir = 'C:\\PyBackup'
# Example on Max OS X and Linux:
# target_dir = '/Users/swa/backup'
# Remember to change this to which folder you will be using

# 3. The files are backed up into a zip file.
# 4. The name of the zip archive is the current date and time
target = target_dir + os.sep + \
    time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# Create target directory if it is not present
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    os.mkdir(target_dir)  # make directory

# 5. We use the zip command to put the files in a zip archive
zip_command = 'zip -r {0} {1}'.format(target,
                                      ' '.join(source))
# -r = recursive


# Run the backup
print('Zip command is:')
print(zip_command)
print('Running:')
print(os.system(zip_command))  # I added this to try to troubleshoot the error
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Successful backup to', target)
else:
    print('Backup FAILED')

# Still can't figure out what the error code -1073741515 means
```

Comment: That return code likely means you're missing a dependency or something when running the `zip` command. Can you try using [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `os.system`? Or other examples of [replacing `os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system). You will want something to be able to capture stdout/stderr.

Comment: I'm not real sure about the syntax of how to use subprocess.check_output. I'm still new to Python, so the link you sent wasn't super clear to me as to how to implement it. Thus, I hope what I added to the code was corrent: subprocess.check_output(zip_command)
Output: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ftbbo\PycharmProjects\helloworld\backup_ver1.py", line 57, in <module>

Comment: subprocess.check_output(zip_command)
  File "C:\Users\ftbbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\ftbbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'zip -r C:\PyBackup\20220705205942.zip C:\Users\ftbbo\PycharmProjects\helloworld' returned non-zero exit status 3221225781.

Comment: The exit status indicates a missing dependency/DLL: https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=3221225781 - can you actually run this `zip` command in the command line (without Python)?

Comment: @wkl - yea, as per the instructions in the book, it said if there were any issues, it recommended copying the command that the code produced and running it in the cli. But it ran just fine. So I don't know if the issue is with Pycharm or Python, or something else...